# I increased size of the disk for my vm using workstation but its not showing increased size

Tags: 14.04, vmware, vmware-workstation

My Ubuntu vm running under vmware workstation had 20GB of storage. 
I increased the storage to 50GB and rebooted but when I do df -h, it still shows only 20GB of storage.

Do I need to run some command to repartition or to assign the new alloted size.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 How to do that.. can you help me with commands?

Comment: My disk space is full so I cant install gparted